# Trying To fill textarea with some data

Tags: csv, firefox, imacros

i've been trying to make this script work , but i just can't figure it out ! I would appreciate if somebody could help me.

So I'll start explaining:

-I have a list of email addresses in a text file , i know imacros only supports csv so what i do is :

1. At the end of each line i replace "\n"  with a "," and save it as a csv.
2. Then i try to paste 25 email addresses.
3. It works , i get the email addresses , but now im stuck here trying to paste the next 25 addresses.
   Here is what i made :

   ```
   VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
   TAB T=1
   'TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
   SET !DATASOURCE ppl.csv
   'SET !LOOP 1
   'SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
   FRAME F=3
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:addmember ATTR=ID:add-members-textarea CONTENT={{!COL1}}<SP>{{!COL2}}<SP>{{!COL3}}<SP>{{!COL4}}<SP>{{!COL5}}<SP>{{!COL6}}<SP>{{!COL7}}<SP>{{!COL8}}<SP>{{!COL9}}<SP>{{!COL10}}<SP>{{!COL11}}<SP>{{!COL12}}<SP>{{!COL13}}<SP>{{!COL14}}<SP>{{!COL15}}<SP>{{!COL16}}<SP>{{!COL17}}<SP>{{!COL18}}<SP>{{!COL19}}<SP>{{!COL20}}<SP>{{!COL21}}<SP>{{!COL22}}<SP>{{!COL23}}<SP>{{!COL24}}<SP>{{!COL25}}
   'TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:addmember ATTR=ID:add-members-add-button
   ```

So the whole idea is to get 25 email addresses , add them to a database , then start from number 26 and add other 25 until there is no more.

Answer (score 0):

//I have used javascript code with imcaros. May be this helps.

```
macro += "TAB T=1" + "\\n";
   macro += "SET !DATASOURCE 39.csv" + "\\n";
   macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\\n";
   macro += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}"+ "\\n"; 



   //here u can stop the macro.js file and start at any value for your use case



for(var i=1;i<50;i++){
   iimSet("i",i);
   iimPlay(macro);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
I must be doing something wrong , but the macros isnt working.
I added the TAG element between the macro += and the for loop but it isnt working.